# Stop being root in the middle of a script that was run with sudo

Tags: linux, bash, shell, root, sudo

There is a list of commands that only succeed when they are prefaced with `sudo`.
There is another list of commands that only succeed when the user runs them without `sudo`.

I want to execute all of these commands from the same script.
I'd like to avoid having to do the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo sudo_command_one;
sudo sudo_command_two;
sudo sudo_command_three;
non_sudo_command;
sudo sudo_command_four;
```

The reason for this, is because sudo has a time-out, and these commands will likely take a long time.  I don't want to be burdened with having to re-type the sudo password occasionally.  I could perhaps extend the time-out of sudo indefinitely, but that is also something I would prefer to avoid if there is an easier way.

Therefore, I'm going to run the script like this:

```
sudo ./script
```

But this will prevent the non-sudo commands from working.
What are the missing commands I need:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo_command_one;
sudo_command_two;
sudo_command_three;
[turn sudo off for a moment]
non_sudo_command;
[ok, turn sudo back on]
sudo_command_four;
```

Unfortunately, the order of the commands cannot be rearranged so that I run all the sudo commands first, followed by all the non-sudo commands(or vice versa).

Comment: You could add `sudo -v` to update the timestamp on the sudo credentials.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a script run by sudo, use:

```
su -c "shell command; shell command" $SUDO_USER
```

within that script to execute commands as the normal user who invoked sudo.

This works because `sudo` sets the environment variable `SUDO_USER` to the original username.

If you have a bunch of commands to run as the original user, you could use a hereis document.

Here is an example script file as proof of concept:

myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Part 1"
echo "now running as:"
whoami
echo "SUDO_USER is:"
echo $SUDO_USER
su $SUDO_USER <<EOF
echo "Part 2"
echo "now running as:"
whoami
echo "SUDO_USER is:"
env | grep ^SUDO_USER
sleep 5
EOF
echo "Part 3"
echo "now running as:"
whoami
echo "SUDO_USER is:"
echo $SUDO_USER
```

And here's the output on `sudo ./myscript.sh`

```
Part 1
now running as:
root
SUDO_USER is:
paul
Part 2
now running as:
paul
SUDO_USER is:
SUDO_USER=paul
Part 3
now running as:
root
SUDO_USER is:
paul
```

Warning: This technique doesn't work so well with nested sudo.  If sudo is nested twice, e.g.

```
sudo su

echo $SUDO_USER
---> me

sudo su
echo $SUDO_USER
---> root
```

SUDO_USER will return root, not the original username.  su $SUDO_USER would then keep running as root. Be careful to avoid that scenario, and it should work ok.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would run it in a script.

```
#! /bin/bash

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root";
   exit 1;
else
    NON_ROOT_USER=$(who am i | awk '{print $1}');
    echo "root ran this echo.";
    sudo -u $NON_ROOT_USER echo "$NON_ROOT_USER ran this echo.";
fi
```

sudo ./script.sh

Comment: Cool. It's interesting that "who am i" and "whoami" return different results.